# Cannot pass scope object to partial

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So im using ngRoute to load different partial html files to my index.html file. The ng-view directive loads the first partial (search.html), and when i click a link in that partial, it loads a second partial (details.html). The link click effectively makes a call (via a controller) to the OMDB API to retrieve a specific movie's details and sets $scope.movieJson = response. When i try to access this in my details.html partial, it doesnt recognise it.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <title>Movie List - Home</title>
 </br>
 </br>
 <div class="container">
  <img class="" src="http://www.movie-list.com/images/logo.png" display="block" margin="auto" width="25%">
 </div>
 </br>
 </br>

</head>
<body>
 <div class='container'>
  <input class="form-control searchBox" ng-show="show" type="text" name="searchBox" ng-model="movies" ng-change="getMovies()" placeholder="Enter your movie search">
  </br>

  <a href="#/" ng-click="reloadPage()" ng-hide="hide"><h3>Search Again</h3></a>
  <div data.ng-view></div>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
 </div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
 <script src="js/config.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

controller.js

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
 $scope.show = true;
 $scope.hide = true;

 $scope.getMovies = function() {
  console.log("Get movies requested in controller");
  $http.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s="+$scope.movies+"&y=&plot=full&r=json").success(function(response) {
   console.log("Get movies requested in controller");
   console.log($scope.movies);
   console.log(response);
   $scope.moviesJson = response;
  });
 };

 $scope.getMovie = function(Title, err) {
  console.log(Title);
  $http.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+Title+"&y=&plot=full&r=json").success(function(response) {
   console.log("Get single movie requested in controller");
   console.log(response);
   $scope.movieJson = response;
   window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
  $scope.show = false;
  $scope.hide = false;
 };

 $scope.reloadPage = function() {
  window.location.reload();
 };
});
```

config.js

```js
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {     
 $routeProvider
 .when('/', {
  templateUrl : 'partials/search.html',
  controller : 'AppCtrl'
 })
 .when('/details', {
  templateUrl : 'partials/details.html',
  controller : 'AppCtrl'
 })
 .otherwise(
 {
  templateUrl : '<div>No Page</div>'
 });
});
```

search.html

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
 <div class="row" vertical-align: middle ng-show="show">
  <div  class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-lg-10">
   <div data-ng-repeat="movie in moviesJson.Search" class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
    <h4><a href="#/details" ng-click="getMovie(movie.Title)">{{movie.Title}}</a></h4>
    <a href="#/details" ng-click="getMovie(movie.Title)" ng-style="{ width : 50px, height : 50px }"><img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{ movie.Poster || 'https://www.myuniverse.co.in/ABMUPictureLibrary/NoImage.jpg' }}"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

details.html

```html
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10 col-lg-10">
 <table class="table" border="1">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr><h4><strong>Title:</strong> {{movieJson.Title}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>Year:</strong> {{movieJson.Year}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>Rated:</strong> {{movieJson.Rated}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>Released:</strong> {{movieJson.Released}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>Runtime:</strong> {{movieJson.Runtime}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>Genre:</strong> {{movieJson.Genre}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>Director:</strong> {{movieJson.Director}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>Writer:</strong> {{movieJson.Writer}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>Actors:</strong> {{movieJson.Actors}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>Plot:</strong> {{movieJson.Plot}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>Language:</strong> {{movieJson.Language}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>Country:</strong> {{movieJson.Country}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>Awards:</strong> {{movieJson.Awards}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>Metascore:</strong> {{movieJson.Metascore}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>IMDB Rating:</strong> {{movieJson.imdbRating}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>IMDB Votes:</strong> {{movieJson.imdbVotes}}</h4></tr>
   <tr><h4><strong>IMDB ID:</strong> {{movieJson.imdbID}}</h4></tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```js
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
 console.log("Worked");
});
```

server.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname = '\public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('', function (req, res) {
 console.log(req.body);
 res.json();
});

app.post('', function(req, res) {
 console.log(req.body);
 res.json(doc);
});

app.listen(3001);
console.log("Server running on port 3001");
```

[End result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbVGm.png)

Comment: Clicking on the link causes an async HTTP GET and loads details.html, yes?  Seems there's no guarantee that the HTTP GET will return before details.html is loaded.  If that's the case it would explain your symptoms.  `$scope.movieJson` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `ng-controller="AppCtrl"`

You are effectively creating 3 different instances , each with it's own scope.

The first is created by the route, then you have 2 nested instances inside that one

Comment: Tried what you said and its still the same.

Comment: Just to clarify, remove ng-controller="AppCtrl" from the 2 partials and leave it in index.html?

Comment: Didn't even notice it there...then you have 4 separate instances. Suggest you create one controller per route and using the routing config for those. Then they will be responsible for what is inside ng-view. Also might be worth going through the tutorial on the documentation site